# Filter elements not matching on a key between two lists in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have two vectors of maps in clojure

```
(def a [{:name "batman" :universe "DC" :email "batman@wayne.com"}
        {:name "flash" :universe "DC" :email "flash@speedfreak.com"}
        {:name "thor" :universe "MARVEL" :email "thor@asgard.com"}])

(def b [{:name "batman" :universe "DC" :email "batman@wayne.com"}
        {:name "flash" :universe "DC" :email "flash1@speedfreak.com"}
        {:name "thor" :universe "MARVEL" :email "thor@asgard.com"}
        {:name "riddler" :universe "DC" :email "riddler@whoami.com"}])
```

The `:name` property in both list are always in sync; i.e., `batman` in `a` is always `batman` on `b` too.

What I want to do, though, is to pick out only rows where email is not matching up.

```
(stuck-on-what-to-write-here)

=> ({:name "flash", :universe "DC", :email "flash1@speedfreak.com"})
```

If I filter out the rows with

```
(filter #(not (contains? (set (map :email a)) (:email %))) b)
```

it returns 2 rows, one with `flash` as it doesn't match and one with `riddler` because.. well, it's not there in a and hence doesn't match!

What do I need to do to get just flash and not riddler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defn mismatch?
  "Returns true if there is any mismatch between corresponding items."
  [a b]
  (= (count (clojure.set/union (set a) (set b)))
     (max (count a) (count b))))
```

If you want a specific name, you could use list comprehension:

```
(defn get-mismatched-emails
  "Returns the name of any superheroes with inconsistent contact records."
  [a b]
  (for [i a j b
        :when (and (= (:name i) (:name j))
                   (not= (:email i) (:email j)))]
    (:name i)))
```

Note that this function is rather inefficient, as it has to compare every combination of pairs between the two lists. Simply by changing your data structure to a map of maps:

```
{"batman" {:universe "DC" :email "batman@wayne.com"}
 "flash"  {:universe "DC" :email "flash@speedfreak.com"}
 "thor"   {:universe "MARVEL" :email "thor@asgard.com"}}
```

you would rather easily be able to scale what you want up to much larger datasets.

```
(for [name (clojure.set/union (set (keys a))
                              (set (keys b)))
      :when (detect-mismatched-data (a name) (b name))]
  name)
```

Comment: hi, thank you, I'm only doing this for a personal project which I probably will abandon when I am bored with it. I am getting the records from two different databases with jdbc mysql connector. I get returned the list as is.. if I have to convert them all to map of maps, then I have to do it manually anyway right? Though in my case it doesn't matter but I would like to know, thanks! The solution you provided works really well.

Comment: Not exactly manually, no. You'd have to write a function to construct a map from each element in the vector, but it wouldn't be too hard. Something of the form `(reduce #(into % (do (stuff (to %2)))) {} a)`, I'd think. If the thought of doing something manually sounds tedious and boring, you probably don't have to!

Comment: yea, sorry, I should have been clearer, by manual I meant iterate through the elements and apply a function etc.. not by hand! - I am pretty sure I'm mixing up the terminology here! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that `"batman"` would be a much better map key than `:batman` here: strings are perfectly fine map keys, and you don't want to convert user data to keywords just to store it in a map.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to add a second condition to your filter on the email. I have no idea about the performance over [galdre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26915281/363674) though!

```
(def a-names (set (map :name a)))
(def a-emails (set (map :email a)))

(filter #(and
          (contains? a-names (:name %))
          (not (contains? a-emails (:email %)))) 
        b)
```

this will output `({:name "flash", :universe "DC", :email "flash1@speedfreak.com"})`

<sub>Also not that I've put `(set (map :name a))` outside filter so it doesn't have to loop through to collect names for each item in b.</sub>

Comment: I was messing with the data to see how slow exactly it would be and I had about 200,000 rows and this was way, way, way faster. about 8 times faster than a `for`!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(filter #(not (contains? (set (map :email b)) (:email %))) a)
```

Returns:

```
({:universe "DC", :name "flash", :email "flash@speedfreak.com"})
```